# how to solve pub get failed(65;)

Tags: flutter

I'm just open VSCode but i'm in the problem with this code.

they are not working at all file.
so I wrote  ':' and then next line show error.

please save me in this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMds6.jpg)

enter code here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX9u3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when pull code you have conflict in pubspec.lock. Remember that all lock file should not push to remote branch such as pubspec.lock or podfile.lock.

In your case. You just remove lock, clean and pub get again.

```
rm -rf pubspec.lock
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change like below and try again.

```
...

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

...
```

Comment: This change not works